# My nokogiri gem conflict with another version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

When I run command to create rails app, i get error Unable to activate rails-dom-testing-1.0.7, because nokogiri-1.5.11 conflicts with nokogiri (~> 1.6.0) (Gem::ConflictError)

How can i uninstall old version of nokogiri? or use new version by default?

Comment: i recommend  you to use  homebrew to manage  your packages , it will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem uninstall nokogiri -v '1.5.11'`